# How to prevent textures (a png file) to repeat in a grid pattern?

Tags: texturing, uv

To whomever it may  concern,

I'm looking to get a singular logo onto my bullet train. It seems every time I go through the process, I end up with the logo repeating itself on a grid pattern. How do I fix this? All I'd like is to be able to add 1 logo, as a png.

Thank you.

https://gyazo.com/3338f4671a248bdd589a88a0558a2e5b

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: Aka a [decal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=decal)

Answer (score 1):

In your image texture node change *Repeat* to *Clip*.
This will show the image only once and rest will be transparent instead of tilting in the case of repeat

[image]

Comment: Many thanks indeed!